# Can we ask about Microsoft Visio?

Tags: support, scope, questions

I have a few questions in the usage of Microsoft Visio. Can I ask questions related to them here?

I know this place is for webapps but still I was thinking if I can ask here.

If not here, is there any other Stack Exchange site for Microsoft applications?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions about desktop applications - which Visio is - should be asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Oh I didn't know this. Thank you very much.